# Couldn't upgrade PHP to 7.3 because of no matching package is available

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04

I am not able to upgrade to php7.3 from 7.2 on ubuntu 16.04, I run the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install php7.3
```

with th following output appears:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php7.3-mongodb' for regex 'php7.3'
Note, selecting 'php7.3-memcached' for regex 'php7.3'
Note, selecting 'php7.3-msgpack' for regex 'php7.3'
Note, selecting 'php7.3-igbinary' for regex 'php7.3'
Note, selecting 'php7.3-uploadprogress' for regex 'php7.3'
Note, selecting 'php-uploadprogress' instead of 'php7.3-uploadprogress'
php7.3-msgpack is already the newest version (2.1.1+0.5.7-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4).
php7.3-mongodb is already the newest version (1.8.1-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4).
php7.3-memcached is already the newest version (3.1.5+2.2.0-4+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4).
php-uploadprogress is already the newest version (1.0.3.1-4-g95d8a0f-5+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+10).
php7.3-igbinary is already the newest version (3.1.6+2.0.8-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
```

and PHP -v still the old version

Comment: You probably still have 7.2 installed, and alternatives is still pointing to it. Run `update-alternatives --list php` to see what's installed. Then delete 7.2 or run `update-alternatives` with `--set` to pick your preferred default.

Comment: I have php7.2 still installed and php7.3 has not installed yet  in the system, I am not able to install it and this is the problem although the repo ppa:ondrej/php was found and updated

Comment: What makes you think 7.3 is not installed yet? There are no errors in your output. It's telling you those packages weren't installed because they were already present.

Comment: when I try to insatll any php package for exampe php7.3-cli , I got: ```E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3-cli'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3-cli'```

Comment: Huh, looks like maybe ondrej dropped support for 16.04, probably because it's now past end-of-support? I'd think the packages should still be available tho, odd.

Comment: [This ppa file](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz) is pretty much empty and has a touch date of a few days ago. Maybe a bug in packaging.

Comment: I think it has still supported as I have another machine with the same specs in another environment and the upgrade has done successfully since 1 week

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ondřej has [removed support for 16.04](https://www.patreon.com/posts/ubuntu-16-04-lts-52120358) just a few days ago:

> As of this moment, all the packages for the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial) have been removed from the repositories.

This explains how it worked ok for you last week, but isn't working today.

Comment: Is the repository still available for ubuntu 18 or ubuntu 20?

Comment: I believe so -- the announcement mentions only 16.04 and the repo files for the other repos aren't empty. (Though I have not actually tried installing recently.)